# PictureLookup macro stopped locating portrait pictures properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a PictureLookup macro set up to show over a hundred pictures. Did my tests and it was all working fine, but I had too many of them stacking on top of themselves (recalculated, removed the deletion part because it caused problems). After that, the portrait ones are added far to the right... Any idea what's going on here?

```
Public Function PictureLookup(Value As String, Location As Range)

Application.Volatile

Dim lookupPicture As Shape
Dim sheetName As String
Dim picTop As Double
Dim picLeft As Double

sheetName = Location.Parent.Name

'Delete current picture if exists
'For Each lookupPicture In Sheets(sheetName).Shapes
'    If lookupPicture.Name = "PictureLookup" Then
'        lookupPicture.Delete
'    End If
'Next lookupPicture
'
'Get position of cell calling the UDF
picTop = Location.Top
picLeft = Location.Left

'Add the picture in the right location
Set lookupPicture = Sheets(sheetName).Shapes.AddPicture _
("F:\DCIM\1000GRMN\DSC00" & Value & ".jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, picLeft, picTop, -1, -1)

'change the picture name
lookupPicture.Name = "PictureLookup"
lookupPicture.Height = 100
PictureLookup = ""

End Function
```

They are supposed to show in the higlighted column Q : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n76O6.jpg

Formula is written :
`=PictureLookup(Q2;Q2)` 
`=PictureLookup(Q3;Q3)`
etc

Comment: I think in formula `=PictureLookup(Q2;Q2)`  semicolon should be replaced with Coma (if Q2 contain required string).  Other issue is all the pictures are named same "PictureLookup". I tested with Name as `"PictureLookup" & Location.Address(False, False)` and also enabled delete section and found working OK. however I sized the picture with Location.Height & Width and deleted line `lookupPicture.Height = 100`  But in my understanding using the otherwise well code as UDF may make the workbook slow and unresponsive (with large pictures).  A single button to refresh all picture would be suffice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I use a semicolon since my Excel is in French (and our default decimal separator is a coma, hence why Excel Fr uses a semicolon). I have done your changes, but it still does the same thing unfortunately. Portrait pictures get far to the right, landscape ones are fine. Funnily enough I have noticed that for portrait pictures, their width gets size the the "Location.Height", while it sizes landscape ones properly. Strange, never had this problem before with this function. Code too long to be posted, basically replaced my "100" with "Location.Height" and changed name.